# Selenium click on button Python

Tags: python, selenium, button, computer-science

I am trying to click on a button using Python Selenium. This is the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="auth_methods">
    <fieldset data-device-index="phone1" class="">
        <h2 class="medium-or-larger auth-method-header">
            Choose an authentication method
        </h2>
        <div class="row-label push-label">
            <input type="hidden" name="factor" value="Duo Push">
            <span class="label factor-label">
                <i class="icon-smartphone-check"></i>
                Duo Push
                <small class="recommended">
                    Recommended
                </small>
            </span>
            <button class="positive auth-button" type="submit" tabindex="2"><!-- -->Send Me a Push</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row-label phone-label">
            <input type="hidden" name="factor" value="Phone Call">
            <span class="label factor-label">
                <i class="icon-call-ringing" alt="" role="presentation"></i>
                Call Me
            </span>
            <button class="positive auth-button" type="submit" tabindex="2"><!-- -->Call Me</button>
        </div>
        <div class="passcode-label row-label">
            <input type="hidden" name="factor" value="Passcode">
            <span class="label factor-label">
                <i class="icon-smartphone-ellipsis" alt="" role="presentation"></i>
                Passcode
            </span>
            <div class="passcode-input-wrapper">
                <input type="text" name="passcode" autocomplete="off" data-index="phone1" class="hidden passcode-input"
                       placeholder="ex. 867539" aria-label="passcode" tabindex="2">
                <div class="next-passcode-msg" role="alert" aria-live="polite"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="positive auth-button" type="submit" id="passcode" tabindex="2"><!-- -->Enter a Passcode
            </button>
            <input name="phone-smsable" type="hidden" value="True">
            <input name="mobile-otpable" type="hidden" value="True">
            <input name="next-passcode" type="hidden" value="None">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="has-token" value="false">
</div>
<button class="positive auth-button" type="submit" tabindex="2"><!-- -->Send Me a Push</button>
```

How do I click that Send Me a Push at the very bottom? I tried to use xpath or class name. 
For example, I did:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="auth_methods"]/fieldset/div[1]/button').click()
```

I also did :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('positive.auth-button')
```

But it is telling me that Unable to locate element.

Answer (score 0):

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='positive auth-button']")
```

***or you can add an id to your button. and use***

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('your-id-here')
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[class='positive auth-button']"}.   It is still giving me an error. What do you mean by add an id? How can I add an id?

Comment: maybe selenium couldn't find your button due to your html structure. Try the find_element_by_id. or maybe you can try "button[class='positive.auth-button']" with dot version. I think you should make your button unique. In your button, <button id='my-new-button-id-here'/> and then use find_element_by_id

Comment: So I think you are right about selenium could not find my button. That makes sense. However, how do I create a unique button? Do I edit it in my browser? Sorry, I am really new to CS.

Comment: if the web application is not yours you cannot of course. Then you either have to use css selector or element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("-insert-xpath-here[contains(text(), '<!-- -->Send Me a Push')]") you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `xpath` to click

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='positive auth-button' and contains(.,'Send Me a Push')]").click()
```

---

Or Use explicit wait and wait for `presence_of_element_located`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/button[@class='positive auth-button' and contains(.,'Send Me a Push')]"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: So I tried both ways. It did not work. The first one shows unable to locate elements. The second one shows the TimeoutException.

Comment: Check the element is present inside any iframe?

Comment: I do not think so. It is very strange. Could it be a security reason?